# What are the best plugins to get jQuery charting/Sparklines to work in IE?

Tags: jquery, charts, modernizr, excanvas, sparklines

I'm having difficulty getting the wonderful jQuery Sparklines plugin to work in various versions of Internet Explorer. (Plugin ref: http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/)

I have to admit that I haven't delved fully into the world javascript hacks to make IE dance. I'm talking about excanvas, the IE libs from dead edwards, or Modernizr, etc. I'm glad I've been given the opportunity to learn more with getting Sparklines to work as my catalyst.

Consequently, I'm wondering if anyone can describe the best extras to work with charting or Sparklines?

A place to start research and testing is what I'm most after.

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: One thing I did not factor in was DOCTYPE. Gareth has recommended making sure you use an HTML4 standard, rather than HTML5 <!DOCTYPE html>. Info here: http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#doc

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Sparklines.js](http://willarson.com/code/sparklines/sparklines.html)

Seems to work in IE7 also.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the jqPlot plugin:

http://www.jqplot.com/

Hope this suits your needs. Cheers